# How i recover the deleted table from database source folder in repository in Informatica

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using Informatica 8.6 with Oracle 11g. By mistakenly, i have deleted a table emp from database source folder in repository.

Can i recover this. or how i can add a new table emp.

please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just re-import the table from database!

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the folder in the repository,  "Find checkouts...". In the next screen, you get the list of checked out objects. Choose the source definition that you deleted, right click and "Undo Checkout".
In Informatica, when you delete an object, it is still checked in. Only if you check out again, does it actually get removed. Until then, you cannot import an object with the same name as the deleted object.

Answer (score 0):

You might have got the fix by now however my input may also put a little flavor to it:

Versioned repository: Go to find check out and select un-do checkout to the deleted object as after deletion it will not go off line until an unless it is checked-in to the repository.

Non-versioned repository: You have to re-import the object with the required DSN with correct credentials.

Hope above said detail can help you to debug further.